# How many times has my process been preempted?

Tags: kernel, scheduling, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote a simple program with a thread which runs on a CPU core. It spins kind of aggressively, and it takes 100% of the CPU core. I can see that with `top` + `1`.

After N minutes, I would like to be able to know:

How many times has the kernel preempted (interrupted) my running thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what Linux has event hooks for, and you can use them with `perf`

## Gathering Statistics

I'd start with something simple:

```bash
sudo perf state -e sched:sched_switch yourprogram
```

Try this:

busyloop.c

```c
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    for (volatile uint_fast64_t i = 0; i < (1ULL<<34); ++i) {
    }
}
```

compile:

```bash
gcc -O3 -o busyloop busyloop.c
```

run:

```bash
$ sudo perf stat -e sched:sched_switch ./busyloop

 Performance counter stats for './busyloop':

               134      sched:sched_switch

      26.534402995 seconds time elapsed

      26.496337000 seconds user
       0.000996000 seconds sys
```

There you have you your answer – kind of. That's the times scheduling switched. That does include your process by itself entering the kernel, instead of getting interrupted.

Subtract the number you get when specifying both `sched_switch` and syscall enter counting:

```bash
$ sudo perf stat -e sched:sched_switch,raw_syscalls:sys_enter ./busyloop

 Performance counter stats for './busyloop':

               765      sched:sched_switch
                30      raw_syscalls:sys_enter

      26.528107216 seconds time elapsed

      26.473054000 seconds user
       0.002994000 seconds sys
```

In this more loaded example run, there were 765 context switches, but only 30 of these were caused by the process doing a syscall by itself.

## Live Statistics

What can be done with `perf stat` can generally also be observed live with the same command line options using `perf top`

```bash
./busyloop &
sudo perf top -e sched:sched_switch,raw_syscalls:sys_enter -p $!
```

(`perf top`, `perf record`, `perf report` without any specified events to observe do something very awesome – they observe how often in a more-or-less regular sampling your CPU cores are in which function. This is an excellent first step in optimizing software and systems in real workload situations. But that leads to far here!)

## In-Depth Tracing

Should you want something that is veeery detailed, `perf sched` is a surprisingly mighty tool.

```bash
$ # make a recording
$ sudo perf sched record -- ./busyloop
[ perf record: Woken up 75 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 161,058 MB perf.data (1458691 samples) ]
$ # evaluate the recording
$ sudo perf sched map
  *A0                               179778.272339 secs A0 => migration/0:17
  *.                                179778.272347 secs .  => swapper:0
   .  *B0                           179778.272413 secs B0 => migration/1:21
   .  *.                            179778.272419 secs
   .   .  *C0                       179778.272494 secs C0 => migration/2:26
   .   .  *.                        179778.272503 secs
   .   .   .  *D0                   179778.272576 secs D0 => migration/3:31
   .   .   .  *.                    179778.272585 secs
   .   .   .   .  *E0               179778.272659 secs E0 => migration/4:36
   .   .   .   .  *.                179778.272670 secs
   .   .   .   .   .  *F0           179778.272714 secs F0 => migration/5:41
   .   .   .   .   .  *.            179778.272733 secs
   .   .   .   .   .   .  *G0       179778.272815 secs G0 => migration/6:46
   .   .   .   .   .   .  *.        179778.272821 secs
   .   .   .   .   .   .  *H0       179778.272948 secs H0 => perf-exec:1315372
………
```

Here, every column is a CPU core, and each row is an event. `man perf-sched` can explain these in more detail than I could. `perf schedule latency` takes a recording and tells you how much latency the execution of each task experienced in scheduling.

```
$ sudo perf sched latency | grep busyloop
  busyloop:1315372      |  26548.094 ms |      677 | avg:   0.055 ms | max:   0.660 ms | max start: 179800.883053 s | max end: 179800.883713 s
```

Pretty neat!

Comment: Man, that's awesome! Thanks so much. One question: What do you mean by a process doing a syscall by itself? Are you saying that certain syscalls (like yield or sleep) will of course cause preemption? Can you give other examples of syscalls causing the thread to be interrupted?

Comment: Every syscall, by definition, hands over control of the CPU to the kernel. So, every syscall means the process doing the syscall stops being scheduled, and the kernel is. The kernel might finish the syscall and directly schedule the process next, or it doesn't. It's hard to call this "being interrupted": the process asked for the kernel to be scheduled by doing a syscall.

Comment: Thanks again, Marcus! My goal here is simple: I'm going to isolate the CPU with `isolcpus`, pin my thread to this isolated cpu and I'm hoping to see as few context switches as possible. I understand there could be hardware interrupts, but still my goal is to minimize interruption. I won't be making any `syscalls` that give back the CPU to the kernel.

Comment: yeah, then chances are you'll see very few. I mean, look at my example above: this was run on one of 8 cores of a normal desktop machine running a firefox with a lot of open tabs (in one of which I was typing my answer). Over the course of 26.5 s, a meager 134 context switches happened (unless I specifically shared the CPU I used with another CPU-hungry task). So, I don't think you'll spend much time doing anything but computation on that CPU core, unless some necessary hardware aspect forces the kernel to take action on that core (which usually doesn't happen, unless you forced some hardware

Comment: to use that very same core)